# Bootstrap 3 carousel slide to certain image

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I got one problem and one question.

1) The next, previous arrows don't work. They appear well, but if i click on it, nothing happens.. Anyone has a clue why?

2) How can I trigger to slide to a certain image by clicking in one of those divs i created below?

You can find my code here below:
Thanks in advance!

```
<div class="row carousel2-container">  
  <div id="carousel2-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<!-- Indicators -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators hidden">
  <li data-target="#carousel2-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel2-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  <li data-target="#carousel2-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>

<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="item active">
    <img src="/assets/uploads/7fb6633be98d5aad669653c706ebfee9.png" alt="carousel1">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="/assets/uploads/7fb6633be98d5aad669653c706ebfee9.png" alt="carousel2">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="/assets/uploads/7fb6633be98d5aad669653c706ebfee9.png" alt="carousel3">
  </div>
</div>

    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel2-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel2-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="row carousel2-container">
  <div class="col-xs-12 carousel2-bottom">
    <div class="col-xs-4 carousel2-item" data-slide-to="0">
        <div class="col-xs-3">

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            dsfkljfldskhfjklqshfkjsd kldsqj flksqjdf lksdj flksqdj flksqdj flksqj lfkqs djflm
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 carousel2-item" data-slide-to="1">
        <div class="col-xs-3">

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            dsfkljfldskhfjklqshfkjsd kldsqj flksqjdf lksdj flksqdj flksqdj flksqj lfkqs djflm
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 carousel2-item" data-slide-to="2">
        <div class="col-xs-3">

        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            dsfkljfldskhfjklqshfkjsd kldsqj flksqjdf lksdj flksqdj flksqdj flksqj lfkqs djflm
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems like you need it to do something like on http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/tabbed-slider-carousel and just add in the indicators/arrows.

Comment: Thanks Aibrean, that's a good link, i'll check that one out tomorrow.

Comment: For question 1 these may help you : 

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp

Comment: also check this :

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_carousel.asp